# Convexity of a function defined by infimum, $\inf_a\{ [x+\sin(x+a)]^2 + [y+\sin(y+a)]^2\}, a \in [-\pi, \pi]$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

It is relatively easy to prove the convexity of
$$\inf_a\{ [x+\sin(x+a)]^2\}, a \in [-\pi, \pi]$$
by finding the zero of $\partial_a[x+\sin(x+a)]^2$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}[x+\sin(x+a)]^2 = 2cos(x+a)[x+\sin(x+a)] = 0\Rightarrow a=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}-x \text{ or } 2n\pi-x-asin(x)$$
and then substituting back to remove $\inf_a$.

This is harder for the 2d extension:
$$\inf_a\{ [x+\sin(x+a)]^2 + [y+\sin(y+a)]^2\}, a \in [-\pi, \pi]$$

because the $a(x,y)$ is no longer easy to solve for. Graphing shows that the function is non-convex.

Is it possible to remove the $\inf_a$ or prove the convexity for the second function without finding zeros for
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left\{[x+\sin(x+a)]^2 + [y+\sin(y+a)]^2\right\}\text{?}$$
I'm not sure how to deal with the infimum, or the non-linearity in both $x$ and $a$.

Comment: Your derivative looks [wrong](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28d%2Fda%29%28x%2Bsin%28x%2Ba%29%29%5E2). Secondly, I don't see why this is zero only when $\cos(x+a)$ is zero.

Comment: Sorry, typo. it's corrected now. I was also being very sloppy with the second solution, because the first solution gives the function at $|x|>1$, and the function is $0$ for $|x|\leq1$. Anyway, I wondering whether it is possible to remove the infimum or prove (non)convexity without finding zeros for $\partial_a[x+sin(x+a)]^2$.

Answer (score -1):

A simplification of the 1d case which could help in the 2d case.
(Since your graph of the latter already shows that it is *not* convex
I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve.)

Since for each $x\in\mathbb R$ the function $[-\pi,\pi]\ni a\mapsto\sin(x+a)\in [-1,1]$ is surjective we can simplify the infimum to
$$\tag{1}
f(x):=\inf_{a\in\mathbb R}\big[x+\sin(x+a)\big]^2=\inf_{b\in[-1,1]}[x+b]^2\,.
$$
Splitting up $x$ into cases
shows that the infimum over $b$ is attained by the following $b\,:$
\begin{align}
x&\in [-1,1]: & b=-x\,,\\
x&\in (1,\infty): & b=-1\,,\\
x&\in (-\infty,-1): & b=+1\,.
\end{align}
Therefore, $f$ is the convex function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}(x+1)^2\,,&x\in(-\infty,-1)\,,\\[2mm]0\,,&x\in[-1,1]\,,\\[2mm](x-1)^2\,,&x\in(1,\infty)\,.\end{cases}
$$
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in 2d, as I stated. I am curious what tools can deal with functions defined by pointwise min/max of non-convex functions in general. (Convex conjugate for example requires linear dependence on x) This is a simple and analytic example to start with.

Comment: It seems simple but I think it is not. The [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate) uses a sup: $f^*(x)=\sup\limits_{p\in\mathbb R}\{xp-f(p)\}$ and is trivially convex since each function $x\mapsto xp-f(p)$ over which the sup is taken is in particular convex.

Comment: Yeah, if it'a actually that simple I probably won't be asking about it.. XD Thanks anyway.